# Trying to insert and update both in one query but not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have tried both `insert` and `update` in one query but not getting output.

```
DB::table('tablename')->update(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
    ['votes' => '2']->insert(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John']
);
```

How can I run a query that will work for both.

Comment: what is this? :) I think u can just insert this array with `votes => 2`

Comment: like: `DB::table('tablename')->insert(['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John', 'votes' => 2])`

Comment: It is possible to laravel with array value.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update and insert in one query because they are different things. 
Sql update query works with where clause for example where id=3 updates where
some column of row which id equal to 3. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

But insert query is for inserting records to database.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

And You use Laravel Eloquent.

```
$update = DB::table('some_table')->where('some_colname', 'some_value')->update([...]);
$insert = DB::table('some_table')->insert([...]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries

Answer (score 0):

In laravel updateOrInsert function inserts or updates a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.

For example :

$attributes=['email'=>'john@example.com','name'=>'John'];

$values=['email'=>'john@example.com','name' =>'John','votes'=>'2'];

DB::table('table name')->updateOrInsert($attributes,$values);

Here with $attributes it is checking if the row exists or not, if exists it will update the row with $values, and if it doesn't exists it will insert $values.